# jQuery: What is the difference between deferred.always() and deferred.then()?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-deferred

Seems to me that both does the same thing.

Docs:

- [deferred.always()](http://api.jquery.com/deferred.always/)
- [deferred.then()](http://api.jquery.com/deferred.then/)

Answer (score 35, accepted):

It would seem that `deferred.then()` allows you to pass two separate callbacks for success and failure, whereas `deferred.always()` takes `n` number of callbacks which will all be called regardless of the outcome of the initial event.

I would say use `deferred.always()` in the cases where success/failure of the initial event are not important

Comment: Also, `.then(fn1, fn2)` can be considered a shorthand for `.done(fn1).fail(fn2)`.

Comment: Wow Thanks. Stupid me. I was staring a the docs for some time now and did not notice the difference.

Comment: Note @Ignitor's answer below, which references the fact that `deferred.then()` callbacks can return _new_ promise objects for further asynchronous processing (what `deferred.pipe()` used to do). Ex: `deferred.then(function() { return someNewDeferredThing; }, function() { return null; });` -- In that case, the done callback will result in tracking the status of a new promise object, while the result of the fail callback will be to keep the original deferred object's status (rejected in this case).

Answer (score 7):

With `.then()` you can provide an individual callback for when the `$.Deferred` is resolved (`done`), and *another* for when the `$.Deferred` is rejected (`fail`).

`.always()`, on the other hand, allows you to provide a callback that always gets executed, whether the `$.Deferred` has been resolved or rejected. In other words, within this callback, it doesn't matter if the AJAX call has failed or has been been successfully executed.

I tend to put code in `.always()` when I want that code to run everytime, and independently of whether the `$.Deferred` was resolved successfully or not. For example, to clear an AJAX loading indicator or to hide a progress bar. Using `.then()` you'd have something like this:

```
$.get("/some/url").then(function () { // done callback
  $(".progress-bar").hide();
}, function () { // fail callback
  $(".progress-bar").hide();
});
```

Whilst if you used `.always()`, you'd just need a single callback, because you *always* want to hide the progress bar, no matter if the `$.Deferred` was resolved or rejected:

```
$.get("/some/url").always(function () {
  $(".progress-bar").hide();
});
```

Answer (score 6):

Prior to jQuery 1.8: `.always(fn)` is equivalent to `.then(fn, fn)`

As of jQuery 1.8: `.always(fn)` is similar to `.then(fn, fn)` but it differs in what is returned (see http://api.jquery.com/deferred.then/ for details)

Answer (score 0):

The big benefit of `then` (as of 1.8) is the capability to chain tasks explicitly because it returns a promise which will be resolved with the result of the callback(s)

Example from documentation:

```
var request = $.ajax( url, { dataType: "json" } ),
    chained = request.then(function( data ) {
      return $.ajax( url2, { data: { user: data.userId } } );
    });

chained.done(function( data ) {
  // data retrieved from url2 as provided by the first request
});
```